# Iphone 4 web application footer is cut off

Tags: ios, iphone, web-applications

I have a web app that looks fine on ipad air but on an Iphone 4s the footer is cutoff.  I have the initial scale set to 1 and if I set it to .5 I can see the footer, but shouldn't work it at scale 1 which means no zoom, correct?  I am not sure what is wrong that is cutting the footer off on the Iphone 4.

Thanks!

Here is a slimmed down version of my code and un-prefixed css

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 10px;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

.page-host {
    min-height: 100vh;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

}

.app-header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 1rem;
    background: #F0CB45;
}

.content-wrapper {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.content {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 20px;
    line-height: 1.6;
}

.icon-bar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background: #F0CB45;
}

.icon-bar a {
    flex: 1;
}

.icon-bar a {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    background: #EFCA51;
}

.icon-bar i {
    display: block;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="prefix.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">  <!--Needed for mobile-->
    <!-- Allow web app to be run in full-screen mode. -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable"
          content="yes">
</head>
<body>
<div class="page-host">
    <header class="app-header">
        <h1>My App</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            <div>Ad at commodi cumque cupiditate dolorem, doloribus eaque eveniet excepturi laboriosam laudantium
                molestiae necessitatibus omnis optio praesentium quaerat quod, repellendus rerum sed sequi sint sit
                sunt
                tempora ut vitae voluptatibus.
            </div>
            <div>Blanditiis esse explicabo fugiat hic in nemo odit omnis porro possimus quam quod reiciendis sequi,
                totam veniam vitae. Alias distinctio ea et eum hic magnam odio officia officiis omnis praesentium!
            </div>
            <div>Aliquam, animi consectetur culpa deleniti dolore eius error ex hic ipsa iste molestias nesciunt
                nisi
                quam recusandae suscipit. Consectetur error fugit sapiente sequi. Atque consequatur incidunt ipsum
                magnam quidem voluptas.
            </div>
            <div>Aspernatur blanditiis consectetur culpa dicta eos et facilis, iste itaque iusto minus molestias nam
                nemo nobis nostrum nulla obcaecati optio quo ratione sed soluta tempora, temporibus velit voluptas,
                voluptatem voluptatum.
            </div>
            <div>Cupiditate excepturi, laborum maxime nisi omnis quis suscipit. Assumenda culpa delectus dolorem
                ducimus
                exercitationem ipsa vero voluptate! Dolor doloremque excepturi quos veritatis. Ex impedit, modi
                nostrum
                officia perferendis suscipit veritatis.
            </div>
            <div>Adipisci, beatae cum dolorem eos exercitationem impedit molestiae obcaecati odio omnis suscipit
                temporibus velit veniam, voluptatibus. A ducimus est ipsa rem vel! Cupiditate dignissimos hic
                laboriosam, perspiciatis rerum tenetur voluptatem.
            </div>
            <div>Cupiditate excepturi, laborum maxime nisi omnis quis suscipit. Assumenda culpa delectus dolorem
                ducimus
                exercitationem ipsa vero voluptate! Dolor doloremque excepturi quos veritatis. Ex impedit, modi
                nostrum
                officia perferendis suscipit veritatis.
            </div>
            <div>Adipisci, beatae cum dolorem eos exercitationem impedit molestiae obcaecati odio omnis suscipit
                temporibus velit veniam, voluptatibus. A ducimus est ipsa rem vel! Cupiditate dignissimos hic
                laboriosam, perspiciatis rerum tenetur voluptatem.
            </div>
            <div>Cupiditate excepturi, laborum maxime nisi omnis quis suscipit. Assumenda culpa delectus dolorem
                ducimus
                exercitationem ipsa vero voluptate! Dolor doloremque excepturi quos veritatis. Ex impedit, modi
                nostrum
                officia perferendis suscipit veritatis.
            </div>
            <div>Adipisci, beatae cum dolorem eos exercitationem impedit molestiae obcaecati odio omnis suscipit
                temporibus velit veniam, voluptatibus. A ducimus est ipsa rem vel! Cupiditate dignissimos hic
                laboriosam, perspiciatis rerum tenetur voluptatem.
            </div>
            <div>Cupiditate excepturi, laborum maxime nisi omnis quis suscipit. Assumenda culpa delectus dolorem
                ducimus
                exercitationem ipsa vero voluptate! Dolor doloremque excepturi quos veritatis. Ex impedit, modi
                nostrum
                officia perferendis suscipit veritatis.
            </div>
            <div>Adipisci, beatae cum dolorem eos exercitationem impedit molestiae obcaecati odio omnis suscipit
                temporibus velit veniam, voluptatibus. A ducimus est ipsa rem vel! Cupiditate dignissimos hic
                laboriosam, perspiciatis rerum tenetur voluptatem.
            </div>
            <div>Cupiditate excepturi, laborum maxime nisi omnis quis suscipit. Assumenda culpa delectus dolorem
                ducimus
                exercitationem ipsa vero voluptate! Dolor doloremque excepturi quos veritatis. Ex impedit, modi
                nostrum
                officia perferendis suscipit veritatis.
            </div>
            <div>Adipisci, beatae cum dolorem eos exercitationem impedit molestiae obcaecati odio omnis suscipit
                temporibus velit veniam, voluptatibus. A ducimus est ipsa rem vel! Cupiditate dignissimos hic
                laboriosam, perspiciatis rerum tenetur voluptatem.
            </div>
            <div>Cupiditate excepturi, laborum maxime nisi omnis quis suscipit. Assumenda culpa delectus dolorem
                ducimus
                exercitationem ipsa vero voluptate! Dolor doloremque excepturi quos veritatis. Ex impedit, modi
                nostrum
                officia perferendis suscipit veritatis.
            </div>
            <div>Adipisci, beatae cum dolorem eos exercitationem impedit molestiae obcaecati odio omnis suscipit
                temporibus velit veniam, voluptatibus. A ducimus est ipsa rem vel! Cupiditate dignissimos hic
                laboriosam, perspiciatis rerum tenetur voluptatem.
            </div>
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="icon-bar">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
            Home
        </a>
            <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            Me
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out the auto for .content was throwing it off it should be

```
.content-wrapper {
    flex: 1;
...
}
```

I think `flex: 1;` equals `flex: 1 1 0` , have to research this but the basis seems to be the issue and `flex:1;` does fix it

It was strange though because on desktop it worked fine and using chrome's ios simulator for iphone 4 it looked fine, but on the actual iphone 4 device it was messed up.